# ASP .NET Singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, singleton

Just want to make sure I am not assuming something foolish here, when implementing the singleton pattern in an ASP .Net web application the static variable scope is only for the current user session, right? If a second user is accessing the site it is a different memory scope...?

Comment: The short answer is no, you're wrong.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194999/are-static-class-instances-unique-to-a-request-or-a-server-in-asp-net

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The static variable scope is for the entire app domain, which means other sessions also have access to it. Only if you have a farm with different servers you would have more than one instance of the variable.

Comment: +1 "Only if you have a farm with different servers you would have more than one instance of the variable".

Answer (score 40):

Static members have a scope of the current worker process only, so it has nothing to do with users, because other requests aren't necessarily handled by the same worker process.

- In order to share data with a specific user and across requests, use HttpContext.Current.Session.
- In order to share data within a specific request, use HttpContext.Current.Items.
- In order to share data across the entire application, either write a mechanism for that, or configure IIS to work with a single process and write a singleton / use Application.

By the way, the default number of worker processes is 1, so this is why the web is full of people thinking that static members have a scope of the entire application.

Answer (score 18):

As others have mentioned, a static variable is [global to the entire application, not single requests.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194999/are-static-class-instances-unique-to-a-request-or-a-server-in-asp-net)

To make a singleton global to only individual requests, you can use the `HttpContext.Current.Items` dictionary.

```
public class Singleton
{
    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton Instance 
    {   
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["yourKey"] == null)
                HttpContext.Current.Items["yourKey"] = new Singleton();
            return (Singleton)HttpContext.Current.Items["yourKey"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, What is the overhead of this? will it be much slower if I am accessing the singleton quite often?

Comment: @Ws You shouldn't notice any performance issues with this approach. The dictionary implementation is pretty efficient so it won't slow your app down even if you access it a lot.

Comment: why should we use "HttpContext.Current.Items" instead of "Session"?

Comment: @Seva The lifetime of HttpContext.Current.Items is the current request. ie. 1 request. HttpContext.Current.Session spans the entire session. ie. multiple requests that are part of the same session.

Comment: That is very nice and exactly what I am looking for. Is there some type save aproach availbe 5 years later?

Answer (score 4):

If you need it to be user or session based then check out the following link.  Otherwise, as Otavio said, the singleton is available to the entire domain.

http://samcogan.com/singleton-per-asp-net-session/

Comment: @Michael Lang: Yes it was, looks like sam changed his content engine.  Updated the link with the new reference.

Answer (score 0):

The singleton is used for the entire Application Domain, if you want to store user session-related data, use HttpContext Session which is designed for that purpose. Of course, you probably have to redesign your class structure to be able to come up with a key-value-pair way of dealing with the data you're trying to work with.

Answer (score -3):

Session for entire application per user.
ViewState for single asp page.