# Session visible on other computers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I have a strange issue, where basically i have a shopping cart using a session. When i deploy the site using IIS7 all looks fine. I add a product to the session on one pc and it displays in my basket. When i access the site from another pc the basket has this item in it!!??

its my understanding that a session instance is unique per user browser is this correct? and if so, how have i managed to do this? I know its probably something stupid but i can't figure it out, any help is much appreciated!

My session cart code is as follows

```
#region Singleton Implementation

        public static readonly ShoppingCart Instance;
        static ShoppingCart()
        {
            // If the cart is not in the session, create one and put it there
            // Otherwise, get it from the session
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["sCart"] == null)
            {
                Instance = new ShoppingCart();
                Instance.Items = new List<CartItem>();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["sCart"] = Instance;
            }
            else
            {
                Instance = (ShoppingCart)HttpContext.Current.Session["sCart"];
            }

        }

        protected ShoppingCart() { }

        #endregion
```

Comment: Your session singleton implementation is wrong. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076459/static-singleton-in-asp-net-session. You must not store the reference in static variable you should only return it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're storing a single static reference to a single global `ShoppingCart`.
This is a horrible idea.

Whenever you write `ShoppingCart.Instance`, it always returns the original value ou set in the static constructor.

You need to get rid of the singleton and always use session.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of `public static readonly ShoppingCart Instance;`

The instance always returns the same for everyone due to static (applies to application level).