# Number of objects created by a page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a calculation class file where I am doing something. I made an object x of the calculation class in .cs file of aspx and called it in aspx using server tag.
Now I am getting hits for that page.
Is that page is going to use the a single object for that class or for every hit will it create a new object?
Is this a good practice of doing coding?

calculation.cs

```
using system;

public calculation()
{
 //some decelerations
}

public string getProduct()
{
return (A*B*C).toString();
}
```

page.aspx.cs

```
public calculation cal = new calculation();
```

page.aspx

```
<%# cal.getProduct()%>
```

Comment: How about sharing your code and maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely dependent upon how you have instantiated the object.

If it's a singleton with a static variable scope then it will be created once *for each app domain*.  If the app recycles then it will be created again.  [ASP .NET Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134511/asp-net-singleton)

If it's a singleton that's stored in the HttpContext, then it will be created once *per request*.  See example here of how to do this: http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/simoneb/archive/2006/08/21/The-ASP.NET-Singleton_2D00_per_2D00_Request-pattern.aspx

If it's a regular variable, then it will be created once every time that page code is called, even it is on the same request.