# What is the catch with ASP.NET singleton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, singleton

I went through a lot of links on stackoverflow, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134511/asp-net-singleton), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194999/are-static-class-instances-unique-to-a-request-or-a-server-in-asp-net) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919095/lifetime-of-asp-net-static-variable) too. Everywhere the answers suggest that, a static variable is static for entire app domain. That is exactly what I was expecting. But the behavior I'm observing is not so. Here's my code:

```
public static class CurrentGrid
{
    private static readonly Grid g;
    static CurrentGrid()
    {
        g = new Grid();
    }
    public static Grid Get { get { return g; } }
}
```

I call this from global.asax.cs AppStart method, like this:

```
if (Application["CurrentGrid"] == null)
    Application["CurrentGrid"] = CurrentGrid.Get;
```

I just want the Grid to be initialized **ONCE**, for entire app life time. But it is not happening. Every time, I get a new instance of Grid object. I tried, using

```
Application["CurrentGrid"] = new Grid()
```

but that too didn't work. As suggested in one of the answers in the above linked questions, I even moved the class definition from App_Start folder to the Models folder, but still the behavior remains the same. Finally I tried using a static constructor to initialize the *Grid* object just once, but still even this static constructor is fired everytime a new request comes.

Also, one another strange behavior that I see is, **Application_Start()** is called for every request too. I thought this method is invoked just once when the application starts for the first time. I guess, I'm mistaken in some very basic/core principles of OOP or ASP.NET framework, because I just can't find any explanation for this behavior. Thanks.

PS: 
1) just a reminder that, my only objective here is to have a singleton *Grid* object for the entire application lifetime. 
2) I'm doing all this inside a MVC5 and SignalR application (in case that matters).

PS: [PROJECT ON GDRIVE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2-g6wkFg3qlb18wTjgzbDR6a2c&authuser=0)

Comment: Are you making changes to your application between requests at all? If so, that would probably (I'm not an expert in ASP.NET, but it would make sense) trigger recompilation and a new AppDomain. I would focus on the fact that Application_Start is called more often than expected - I suspect that's the simplest symptom of the cause of everything else going wrong.

Comment: @JonSkeet No, nothing I believe that should cause recompilation. Could it be because of some SignalR/OWIN stuff ???

Comment: `Application_Start()` should definitely only be called once (certainly not very often). Can you check the call stack to see if something is invoking it?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, but you should look carefully at all the logs you can find, then start stripping as much of your app out as you can, repeatedly checking the symptoms. It definitely sounds like something isn't right - your expectation of Application_Start only being called once is right.

Comment: @RowanFreeman Nothing in the call stack either. For every request (refresh of page) , I get the breakpoint to hit inside Application_Start method.

Comment: Is it possible that something changes your web.config?  That will couse the application restart.

Comment: The static property `CurrentGrid.Get` can be accessed from any controller / view, so why are you using `Application`? The `Application` object is not thread-safe and you need to do some manual locking/unlocking before you edit its value to prevent race conditions.

Comment: @RuslanDayanov What could be the possible factors to change the web.config during application runtime ? I've no idea about that. But, I believe there isn't like this. It is a very simple application from my point of view. :)

Comment: @arao6 This was not my first attempt. After doing many other things, at last, I reached here, when I thought I should post this as a question on SO. But, as pointed on in the comments, the main problem is the Application_Start being called multiple times.

Comment: Do you have any strange Web.config or IIS settings? Perhaps an application pool is constantly being recycled?

Comment: @RowanFreeman Please have a look at the project files if you don't mind, that I've linked in the question in the update. Sorry, if this is asking too much. :)

Comment: When I run the solution, `Application_Start()` is only called once.

Comment: Ensure you aren't writing any log entries to the bin folder.

Comment: @RowanFreeman I'm running this app on VS13 on Win8.1. What about you ??? But yes, after what you said, I think, I remember this behavior happening only from today. Yesterday, things were fine (I guess).

Comment: @aleha I'm not writing any logs. But, I'm updating a text file inside the bin folder. Could it possibly matter ???

Comment: @aleha is correct. By writing to the bin folder, it's forcing the application to restart. +1

Comment: @MrClan try to remove this file to some other location and check.

Comment: @aleha you are right. Please post your comment as an answer, so that I can mark it as correct. Many thanks for your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you aren't writing any log entries (create or modify files) to the bin folder.

Comment: **Indeed writing anything into the bin folder or any of its sub-folders causes the application to be recompiled and restarted.**

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this would help?

```
static CurrentGrid()
{
   if(g == null)
   {
      g = new Grid();
   }
}
```

Or maybe even better;

```
public static class CurrentGrid
{
    private static readonly Grid g;
    static CurrentGrid()
    {
        //Do Grid things her
    }
    public static Grid Get { 
                              get 
                              { 
                                if(g == null)
                                { 
                                   g = new CurrentGrid(); 
                                }

                                return g; 
                              } 
                           }
}
```

Doing it this way, you will definitely only get one Grid-object, unless you dispose it ofcourse.

Comment: I don't think this will work. It sounds like the app is restarting after each request (which isn't normal). This would mean that all state is lost.

Comment: @Dion yes, for every request the g is always null. Since the application is seemingly running as an entirely new application (just analogically saying).

Comment: My apologies for not reading the whole question. It seems this is indeed not the problem. I will delete this post after you've read this comment.