# What is the difference between the Page and ViewBag dynamic objects in MVC3?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

A dynamic object `Page` can be found in `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase`, the abstract class which `WebViewPage` inherits from.

A dynamic object `ViewBag` can be found in `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`.

Both can propagate up from a view to it's layout page.

The other difference I can see is that `ViewBag` can be used in the Controller, whereas `Page` is only available in the view. Are there any other differences I should know about?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429079/what-is-the-difference-between-viewdata-pagedata-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Page` and `ViewBag` are dynamic and they are wrapper around dictionaries.

`Page` is the dynamic wrapper around `PageData` dictionary. `ViewBag` is the dynamic wrapper around `ViewData` dictionary.

When talk about differences,

`ViewBag` is used to share data between controller and view or even we can use to share data between a main view and partial view. So the ViewBag can be accessed from both the controllers and views.

`Page` is a little different thing, it can't be accessed from controllers and it is used to pass data between a main page and a partial page.

See an example here of using `Page` to pass data between a main view and partial view.

**Main.cshtml**

```
@{
   Page.Name = "Mark;
}

@RenderPage("DisplayName.cshtml"); // partial view
```

**DisplayName.cshtml**

```
<p>
Name: @Page.Name
</p>
```

Not that I'm using the `RenderPage` to render the partial view also the partial view is located in the same directory where the main view is located.

Comment: It may help to point out that `ViewBag` is a property of *both* `WebViewPage` and `ControllerBase` and the data from one is copied into the other.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Can you please elaborate your comment.As how does it get copied into other.