# Set a page title from a PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewbag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modifying MVC 3 ViewBag in a partial view does not persist to the _Layout.cshtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974027/modifying-mvc-3-viewbag-in-a-partial-view-does-not-persist-to-the-layout-cshtml)

I'm trying to set a pageTitle from a PartialView

Here is my code:

**PartialView template:**

```
@{
    ((WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).ViewBag.Title = "Page title";
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<title> @ViewBag.Title</title>
```

How to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974027/modifying-mvc-3-viewbag-in-a-partial-view-does-not-persist-to-the-layout-cshtml

Comment: I've already visited it, but I'm looking for a more "convinient" solution!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not something that a partial should do. It's just not its responsibility to modify the parent view `ViewBag`. And in addition to that it's not possible. [Quote from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial.aspx):

> When a partial view is instantiated, it gets its own copy of the
>   ViewDataDictionary object that is available to the parent view. The
>   partial view therefore has access to the data of the parent view.
>   However, if the partial view updates the data, those updates affect
>   only the partial view's ViewData object. The parent view's data is not
>   changed.

You could always do the *workarounds* [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974027/modifying-mvc-3-viewbag-in-a-partial-view-does-not-persist-to-the-layout-cshtml) but please don't. Partials should not be setting any parent state. They should not know anything about the parent.

Comment: Darin, I know this is old, and you are clearly an expert. However, isn't the point of "ViewBag" to be a universal access point for "general view data"? I understand the "separation of concerns" point, but I can't think of a circumstance where the **dynamic** ViewBag in a partial needs to be unaware of the **dynamic** ViewBag in the parent view. If it was strongly-typed, yes.

Comment: I have a wizard, and each step is a partial. I want to change the ViewBag Title based on the step I'm on without reloading the whole page, when the step + partial I'm on changes