# Change page title on error ASP.NET Core MVC without javascript

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, page-title

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application.

I need to append a page title with error: whenever the server validation fires through clicking on a button and Model state has errors.

At the moment - I am changing page title on each page through using shared view as follows:

Here is the logic defined for page title - in the `_Layout.cshtml`.

```
@if (ViewData["Title"] != null)
{
<title> 
    @ViewData["Title"] - Sample Application
</title>
}
```

And on each `viewpage.cshtml` - we are changing page title the following way. Please note, if I define the logic of changing page title with

```
ViewData["Title"] = "Error :" +ViewData["Title"]
```

it works fine.

```
@page
@model SampleModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "What do you do?";
}

@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error: " + ViewData["Title"];
}

<partial name="_ErrorSummary" model="ModelState" />
```

Also, I have a shared components for displaying error summary which is on each page.

```
<partial name="_ErrorSummary" model="ModelState" />
```

And this is the code inside the partial view

```
@model Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary

@if (!Model.IsValid)
{    
   ViewData["Title"] = "Error: " + ViewData["Title"];  //  I want something like this
     
   <div class="govuk-error-summary" aria-labelledby="error-summary-title" role="alert" data-module="error-summary">
   <h2 class="govuk-error-summary__title" id="error-summary-title">
        There is a problem
   </h2>
   <div class="govuk-error-summary__body">
        <ul class="govuk-list govuk-error-summary__list">
            @foreach (var modelError in Model)
            {
                var errorField = modelError.Key;
                foreach (var error in modelError.Value.Errors)
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="#@errorField">@error.ErrorMessage</a>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

So validation is happening on all server sides (We are not using any javascript).

What I want whenever a button is clicked and it throws error on that page summary, the Page title should get appended with "Error : " + existing Page title

How do I do this from one centralised position. Please if anyone can help. Ideally I like to do this in shared error summary view or any bright ideas. Many thanks

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue in my side, and it's true that when I used `ViewData["Title"] = "Error: " + ViewData["Title"];` in the main page, it worked well but it didn't work when use this in the partial view. So the issue can be summarized as how to change view title in the partial view. But per my searching, it's impossible. Because title had been loaded before partial view is rendered. See this [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33521588). And we can use js `document.title = '@ViewBag.Title';`