# pass a value from partial value to layout view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

To send a value from partial view to layout view .  i used in partial view as

```
viewbag.var="Device"
```

and retrieve value on layout view by

```
<h1> @viewbag.var </h1>
```

but not showing any values.plaese help .thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use (ViewBag) instead of (viewbag)

Comment: i tried it but not working

Comment: The partial uses a separate `ViewDataDictionary`. The [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974027/modifying-mvc-3-viewbag-in-a-partial-view-does-not-persist-to-the-layout-cshtml) give a few options you could consider

Comment: @Stephen I need to print the separete heading for each partial view.. how can I implement that?

Comment: Then why don't you include the heading in the partial? But the link I gave in my last comment has some solutions.

Comment: I want to print the headings on dashboard section ,which is in the layout view. @stephen

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TempData: `TempData["var"]="Device"`