# Static variables in web applications

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session, static-members

Can I use static variables in my web application ? what are the alternatives to static ? When I use static variables in pages and more than one user use the application, it makes conflict data (incorrect data).

What are the limits of using static members?

Are static members shared in memory?

Comment: A related question with good answers is at https://stackoverflow.com/q/194999.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider storing your shared variables in the HttpApplication object or in the Cache object.

However, if you are trying to store values for each user separately, you should store those values in a Session variable.

Static variables inside Asp.Net are shared in the memory space of the w3svc.exe process and are NOT thread-safe.  They can be accessed and modified by any user of the application.  This could lead to unwanted modifications, unless you write your own lock mechanism around the storage of those values.

You should try a syntax like:

```
Application["KEY"] = value;
```

to store shared application-wide data and

```
Session["KEY"] = value;
```

to store data on a per-user basis

You can use the WebCache object to store data in the web server's memory with expiration conditions.  Syntax for that looks similar to:

```
Page.Cache.Insert("KEY", "VALUE", null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
```

More on the syntax of managing the WebCache object can be found at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx

Comment: thanks  a lot < two more questions please:1- when to use static variable 2- if i want to persist the data for each user, is the session variable is the only solution , especially when talk about performance the session may cause some problems

Comment: In Asp.Net, my preference is NOT to use static variable for shared data points.  I would prefer to use the Cache object (edit coming shortly to show syntax example) so that I can control the lifetime of my shared data points.

Comment: The Session is the easiest solution to store per-user values.  If you are storing large objects (think Datasets) then your performance will degrade.  Also note:  Session can be stored in Asp.Net State Server or SQL server on a foreign machine, allowing you to maintain these user specific data points across web servers in a webfarm environment

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to what @Jeff Fritz has said, an IIS application creates an AppDomain in which your assemblies are loaded. Just like the rules of a normal windows application, if a class such as

```
public static class Something
{
    public static string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

...then only a single `Something.SomeString` property is available *per* AppDomain. The W3SVC process manages the AppDomain, but the is no guaruntee of thread safety (as an AppDomain can be service multiple requests). If you are using read-only static properties, it's probably fine (such as reading config values). If you are making mutable properties that change through the lifetime of a request, its better to use one of the storage mechanisms detailed in other questions here.