# static dictionary c# shows each time same value

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I have a static dictionary that i create globally. I declare it like this =>

```
    static Dictionary<int, Artikels> dicArtikels = new Dictionary<int, Artikels>();
```

Artikels is a class i have created to store the products.

```
            for (int rijenTeller = 0; rijenTeller < aantalRijen; rijenTeller++)
            {

                Artikels artikel = new Artikels();

                if (dicArtikels.ContainsKey(rijenTeller))
                {
                    artikel = dicArtikels[rijenTeller];
                }
                else
                {
                    dicArtikels.Add(rijenTeller, artikel);
                }

                        artikel.naam = txtNameInstance.Text;
                        artikel.prijs = txtPriceInstance.Text;

                        dicArtikels[rijenTeller] = artikel;
                        artikel = null;
             }
```

Well when i print the output with a button like below it's always showing the value of the last instance. That't not what i want. I want the value of the seperate instances but they are always getting the same value. =>

```
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Artikels artikel = new Artikels();
            artikel = dicArtikels[0];
            Response.Write(artikel.naam.ToString() + " -- " + artikel.prijsExclBTW.ToString());

            artikel = dicArtikels[3];
            Response.Write(artikel.naam.ToString() + " -- " + artikel.prijsExclBTW.ToString());

            artikel = dicArtikels[1];
            Response.Write(artikel.naam.ToString() + " -- " + artikel.prijsExclBTW.ToString());

            artikel = dicArtikels[2];
            Response.Write(artikel.naam.ToString() + " -- " + artikel.prijsExclBTW.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Foutbericht Artikelchangedssssssss: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use a static dictionary in ASP.NET?All users will share the same values and you're getting concurrency issues and other interesting things.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Right, he's up for many other "interesting things", none of which is "interesting" in a particularly good way :-)

Comment: All the names are being set to the same thing: artikel.naam = txtNameInstance.Text;   Same with prijsExclBTW.

Comment: See [Are static class instances unique to a request or a server in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194999/are-static-class-instances-unique-to-a-request-or-a-server-in-asp-net)

Comment: Well instead of a dictionary what would you use?